# How to reduce DB queries?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Models:

```
class Technology(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    technology = models.ManyToManyField(Technology, blank=True, null=True)
```

Views:

```
def portfolio(request, page=1):
    sites_list = Site.objects.select_related('technology').only('technology__name', 'name', 'slug',)
    return render_to_response('portfolio.html', {'sites':sites_list,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template:

```
{% for site in sites %}
<div>
    {{ site.name }},
    {% for tech in site.technology.all %}
        {{ tech.name }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

But in that example each site makes 1 additional query to get technology list. Is there any way to make it in 1 query somehow?

Comment: Do you want to generate a SQL join in the end? Django's way to generate joins is documented [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships), but I guess you've already read it.

Comment: In template in main loop I want to display all technologies assigned to the each site. Technologies are assigned by m2m relation. So I run subloop as You can see in code above.
I want to reduce the number of queries executed by those subqueries. I want to know, if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is an efficient way to do reverse foreign-key lookups. A generic approach is:

```
qs = MyRelatedObject.objects.all()
obj_dict = dict([(obj.id, obj) for obj in qs])
objects = MyObject.objects.filter(myrelatedobj__in=qs)
relation_dict = {}
for obj in objects:
    relation_dict.setdefault(obj.myobject_id, []).append(obj)
for id, related_items in relation_dict.items():
    obj_dict[id].related_items = related_items
```

I wrote a blogpost about this a while ago, you can find more info here: http://bit.ly/ge59D2

Comment: What if I have m2m not ForeignKey?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the m2m relationship in your code. I haven't tested this but what about: 1) Loading the intermediate table as a qs (I think this is only possible if you specify a custom intermediate table), 2) Loading 2 more qs from both sides of the m2m relationship with (myrelatedobj__in=qs), and then joining the 2 by hand? It shouldn't take more than 3 queries.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Using Django's [session framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#module-django.contrib.sessions); load list `request.session['lstTechnology'] = listOfTechnology` on startup. And use session in rest of the app.

Comment: Yhm, so there is no way to reduce it? Another way is cache but I'm wondering if there's way to do it somehow.